# Prove that in every coloration of the following graph, there exists one red or/and one yellow triangle.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle, coloring, ramsey-theory

We have the following graph:
[image: Graph]

whose every line is colored either red or green.

Prove that in every possible coloration there exists one **red** or/and one **green triangle**.

*This problem was introduced in reference to the **Dirichlet's box principle**.*

Comment: The graph is a complete graph of $6$ vertices and this kind of problem is related to [Ramsey Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey's_theorem), in particular you're trying to show that $R(3,3) = 6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple proof, although I am not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Consider this sub-graph

[image]

Instead of colours, I have used numbers. The three edges are coloured $1$. To avoid having a triangle, with all its edges coloured the same, we should colour $BD$, $BC$ and $CD$ with color $2$. Then, it is easily seen that the triangle $BCD$ makes a triangle of all edges coloured $2$, as in the next picture.

[image]

If there is such an structure in the coloured graph, then we definitely have a triangle of one colour. Now, just consider one of the vertices of the main graph and the edges connected to it. There are exactly $5$ edges, incident to the vertex and they are either coloured $1$ or $2$. According to pigeon-hole principle, there are at least $3$ of the $5$ edges, that are coloured the same. Those edges are exactly what we need to use the described structure, to show that there is a uni-coloured triangle.